# Find elements surrounding an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, I want to get the elements surrounding a particular element in that array.

For example if I have the following:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6]
 [8,9,7,5,2,6]
 [1,6,8,7,5,8]
 [2,7,9,5,4,3]
 [9,6,7,5,2,1]
 [4,7,5,2,1,3]]
```

How do I find all the 8 elements around any of the above elements? And how do I take care of elements at the edges?

One way I figured out is, to write a 9 line code for this , which is obvious, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Use modulo (`%`) to take care of the cases at the edges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                for (x = Math.max(0, i - 1); x <= Math.min(i + 1, array.length); x++) {
                    for (y = Math.max(0, j - 1); y <= Math.min(j + 1,
                            array[i].length); y++) {
                        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < array.length
                                && y < array[i].length) {
                            if(x!=i || y!=j){
                            System.out.print(array[x][y] + " ");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
```

Thanks to all the people who have answered, but i figured it out with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652123/1287576) which i found just now, and above is the solution. thanks again :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use 'direction array' in form

```
[[-1,-1], [-1,0],[1,0]..and so on]
```

And method which takes point coordinate and iterates through direction array -> add direction numbers to coordinates, check indexes are not out of bounds and collect results.
Something like this:

```
private static int[][] directions = new int[][]{{-1,-1}, {-1,0}, {-1,1},  {0,1}, {1,1},  {1,0},  {1,-1},  {0, -1}};

static List<Integer> getSurroundings(int[][] matrix, int x, int y){
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int[] direction : directions) {
        int cx = x + direction[0];
        int cy = y + direction[1];
        if(cy >=0 && cy < matrix.length)
            if(cx >= 0 && cx < matrix[cy].length)
                res.add(matrix[cy][cx]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hi, nice solution. Is it possible to extend this to, for example, getting the surrounding elements around an inner set of surrounding elements of a single index? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**For (i, j) ->**

```
              (i - 1, j - 1)
              (i - 1, j)
              (i - 1, j + 1)

              (i, j - 1)
              (i, j + 1)

              (i + 1, j - 1)
              (i + 1, j)
              (i + 1, j + 1)
```

Now, at the edges, you can check for `num % row == 0`, then its at row edge...
and , `num % col == 0` then its column edge..

**Here's is how you can proceed: -**

Given an index `(i, j)`.. You can find elements in a rows adjacent to `j` for `i - 1`, then `i`, and then `i + 1`.  (**NOTE** : - for index `i` you just have to access `j - 1`, and `j + 1`)

Subsequently you also can check for the `row edge` and `column edge`..

Here, you can look at the code below, how it can happen: -

```
    // Array size
    int row = 6;
    int col = 6;
    // Indices of concern
    int i = 4;
    int j = 5;

    // To the left of current Column
    int index = i - 1;
    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++) {
        if (index % row > 0 && ((j + k)  % col) > 0) {
            System.out.println(arr[index][j + k]);
        }
    }


    // In the current Column
    index = i;

    // Increment is 2 as we don't want (i, j)
    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k = k + 2) {            
        if (index % row > 0 && ((j + k)  % col) > 0) {
            System.out.println(arr[index][j + k]);
        }
    }

    // To the right of current Column
    index = i + 1;
    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++) {
        if (index % row > 0 && ((j + k)  % col) > 0) {
            System.out.println(arr[index][j + k]);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE** : - The above code can further be simplified.. But I leave that task to you..
**HINT**: - You can reduce one for loop from there..

Comment: Seems there are some `1`s that should be either `i` or `j` (case 2 and case 7).

Comment: @Rohit Jain: thanks, i figured that out, but, thing is i have to do this for all elements of the multidimensional array, so i need to figure out a generalized way traverse through all neighbouring elements

Comment: @vineetrok If you change each `(i, j)` to `(i % rows, j % cols)` it will work as a general case.

Comment: @Baz.. No that is what I have written.. Initially I wrote `1` in 2nd case, but then I replaced it with `i`.

Comment: @vineetrok.. Before accessing the index, you would need to check whether your (x-index % rows >= 0) and (y-index % col >= 0) then only you can access it..

Comment: @RohitJain I don't understand your comment to me. The comment to vineetrok is not correct. You don't have to check it beforehand. You can use modulo within the access. See me previous comment.

Comment: @Baz.. Actaully earlier I wrote my 2nd element: - `(i - 1, j)` as `(1 - 1, j)`.. So I thought you were talking about that thing in your first comment.. And regarding boundary condition, yes we don't need to check prior, we can just access by modulo.. I was giving an idea to OP.. Thanks :)

Comment: @vineetrok.. You can check the code.. it will make you understand better.. And do see my UPDATE and HINT below the code..

Comment: @Baz.. Actually you need to check for the boundary value prior.. Else, the index will move to the beginning.. If we access them without checking.. See my updated code.. And comment on it..

Comment: @RohitJain No, you don't have to check it prior. Let's say you want to access index `-1` and you have 8 rows. Then `arr[-1 % 8]` is equal to `arr[7]` which is a valid index and the correct one as well.

Comment: @Baz.. Yeah it is valid, but `arr[7]` doesn't count among the one surrounding `arr[0]`.. So, to eliminate the use of them, we need to check..

Comment: @Baz.. I thought he wanted to avoid moving out off `edge`.. Because if we continue the cycle to the other end, when edge is reached.. That will not exactly be adjacent to the `edge` element.. I think only OP can tell what he wants..  (My current code, will stop at the EDGE, and if we don't check the condition, it will move to other end.)

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for the answer, i already found a way to do this. i posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Base case is just to obtain neighbour elements by indexing shifting. For `(i,j)` it will be `(i + 1, j)`, `(i - 1, j)`, etc.

On the edges I use two approaches:

1. Modulo `%` operator to avoid `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, but it sometimes confuse with wrong elements indexation.
2. Wrap your matrix with one layer of *default elements*. It adds some extraspace for holding matrices, but makes your code more readable without catching exception, lot ifs and so on. This trick often used when representation maze as matrix.

Example: your default element is 0.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 0
0 2 6 7 3 0
0 1 3 5 7 0
0 2 4 6 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note: do not forget iterate through **actual** array size, not extended.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for your problem written in Ruby. **Instead of calculating if element is at edge you could access elements "over" the edge and handle "nil" values or exceptions that happen there.** Then remove "nil" values from final list. This solution is not as good as calculating if some "point" is over the edge or not.

```
big_map = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],
           [8,9,7,5,2,6],
           [1,6,8,7,5,8],
           [2,7,9,5,4,3],
           [9,6,7,5,2,1],
           [4,7,5,2,1,3]]

# monkey patch classes to return nil.
[NilClass, Array].each do |klass|
    klass.class_eval do
        def [](index)
            return nil if index < 0 or index > self.size rescue nil
            self.fetch(index) rescue nil
        end
    end
end

class Array

    # calculate near values and remove nils with #compact method.   
    def near(i,j)
        [ self[i - 1][j - 1], self[i - 1][j - 0], self[i - 1][j + 1],
          self[i - 0][j - 1],                     self[i - 0][j + 1],
          self[i + 1][j - 1], self[i + 1][j - 0], self[i + 1][j + 1],
        ].compact
    end
end

puts big_map.near(1,1).inspect
# => [1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 1, 6, 8]

puts big_map.near(0,0).inspect
# => [2, 8, 9]

puts big_map.near(5,5).inspect
# => [2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on he same problem and came up with a small optimized solution to find the surrounding numbers of any point in a 2D matrix, hope this helps, please comment if I can shorten the logic somehow
Code:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] arg){

        int[][] arr = {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25}};
        //int[][] arr = {{width,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x = 2, y = 2;
        int width = 2; //change the value of width, according to the requirement 
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                if( (i == (x-width) && ( (y+width) >= j && j >= (y-width))) || (i == (x+width) && ( (y+width) >= j && j >= (y-width))) || (j == (y-width) && ( (x+width) >= i && i >= (x-width))) || (j == (y+width) && ( (x+width) >= i && i >= (x-width)))  ){
                    //if( x >= 0 && i < (i+width) && y >= 0 && j < (j+width))
                        {
                        al.add(arr[i][j]);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(al);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention if you want cyclical neighbours for edges or ignores cyclical neighbours. Assuming you want cyclical neighbours here is the code,

```
List<Integer> getNeighbours(int[][] mat, int x, int y){
  List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int rows = mat.length;
  int cols = mat[0].length;
  for(int i=-1,i<=1;i++)
    for(int j=-1;j<=1;j++)
      if(i||j) ret = ret.add(mat[(x+i)%rows][(y+j)%cols]);
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(x-1, y-1) -> upper left
(x-1, y) -> left
(x-1, y+1) -> lower left
```

---

```
(x, y+1) -> up
(x, y) -> current position
(x, y-1) -> down
```

---

```
(x+1, y+1) -> upper right
(x+1, y) -> right
(x+1, y-1) -> lower right
```

You can use this as guide. Now all you need to do is add them in a try catch.

```
 for( int x=0; x<arr.length; x++ ){
  for(int y=0; y<arr[x].length; y++){
  if( arr[x][y] == 8 ){
    try{
      System.out.println("Upper Left is: " + arr[x-1][y-1]);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
     //do something
    }


    try{
      System.out.println("Left is: " + arr[x-1][y]);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
     //do something
    }

    //.....and others
   }
  }
```

Comment: You should do boundary checking using `modulo (%)` operator.. You don't need `try-catch` blocks for this thing..

Comment: @gekkostate If you change the exception, why not change the other one as well?

Comment: @Baz Sorry about that, I didn't see that exception.