# How to handle List of list Integer and find neighbours?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, runtime, time-complexity

I am currently trying to solve a problem where the input should be as following

```
int hours(int rows, int columns, List<List<Integer> > grid)
```

Where list grid is a Matrix of 0 and 1 ( 0 means not complete , 1 means complete ) as following:

```
0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0
```

Each value represent a machine in a network sending files to each other, So if the value is "1" then this node is able to send the files to **ALL NEIGHBORS** (Diagonal ones does not count only up/down/right/left).The issue is that once a 0 becomes a 1 ( affected by the neighbor cell ) it cannot send the file to any other neighbor before 1 HOUR.

The goal of the problem is to return how many hours shall it take before all the nodes receive the files? ( in other words all the Matrix becomes 1. **Considering Run time complexity**

For visual explanation: ( After the first hour this should be the state of the matrix which is considered as an iteration):

```
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1
 1 1 1 0 1
```

So, I followed an approach where I loop over the matrix looking in the provided grid and appending values in a temporary array ( as I don't know how to update or append the list values inside the main List). Then once the row index has reached the max i add 1 hour to an int variable and add values to the main grid.

I know the below code is not still working/complete and may have syntax mistakes but you get the idea and the approach.

My Question is, Is there any easier and efficient method than mine?? I also found a solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744657/12582441) But that only works with 2D arrays if my idea is worth it. However, wouldn't these 4 nested loop mess up the complexity of the code?

```
    List<List<Integer>> grid2 = grid1;
    boolean received= false;
    int hours=0;
    int rows_Temp = 0 ;
    int columsTemp = 0 ;
    int[][] grid2 = null ;
    while(rows_Temp<rows&&!received)
    {
        if(rows_Temp==rows-1)
        { 
            rows_Temp=0;
        }
        if(rows_Temp==0) 
        {
            //create an array with the grid dimention
            grid2= new int[rows][columns];
        }
        //manage top left corner
        if(rows_Temp==0 && columsTemp == 0 ) 
        {
            //find right & down
            int center= grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp);
            int right = grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp+1);
            int down  = grid.get(rows_Temp+1).get(columsTemp);


            if(center==1)
            {
                if(right==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp][columsTemp+1] = 1;
                }
                if(down==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp+1][columsTemp]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        //manage top right corner
        else if(rows_Temp==0 && columsTemp == columns-1)
        {
            //find left and down
            int center= grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp);
            int left = grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp-1);
            int down  = grid.get(rows_Temp+1).get(columsTemp);

            if(center==1)
            {
                if(left==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp][columsTemp-1] = 1;
                }
                if(down==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp+1][columsTemp]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        //mange down left corner of the array
        else if(rows_Temp==rows-1 && columsTemp == 0)
        {
            //find up and right
            int center= grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp);
            int right = grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp+1);
            int up  = grid.get(rows_Temp-1).get(columsTemp);

            if(center==1)
            {
                if(right==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp][columsTemp+1] = 1;
                }
                if(up==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp-1][columsTemp]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        //manage down right corner
        else if(rows_Temp==rows-1 && columsTemp == columns-1)
        {
            //find left and up
            int center= grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp);
            int left = grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp-1);
            int up  = grid.get(rows_Temp-1).get(columsTemp);

            if(center==1)
            {
                if(left==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp][columsTemp-1] = 1;
                }
                if(up==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp-1][columsTemp]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        //manage left sides but not corners
        else if(rows_Temp!=0&& rows_Temp!=rows-1&& columsTemp==0)
        {
            int center= grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp);
            int right = grid.get(rows_Temp).get(columsTemp+1);
            int up  = grid.get(rows_Temp-1).get(columsTemp);
            int down  = grid.get(rows_Temp+1).get(columsTemp);

            if(center==1)
            {
                if(right==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp][columsTemp+1] = 1;
                }
                if(up==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp-1][columsTemp]=1;
                }
                if(down==0)
                {
                    grid2[rows_Temp+1][columsTemp]=1;
                }
            }  
        }    

        if(columsTemp==columns-1)
        {
            columsTemp=0;
            rows_Temp++;
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            columsTemp++;
        }


    }
    System.out.println("------------");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Based on your example, I presume diagonal neighbors don't count.

Comment: yes only up / down / right / left

Comment: You should do a breadth-first search starting with the initial 1s.  The number of levels required to traverse all cells is the number of hours to fill the matrix.

Comment: OK thanks i will search the algorithm,  but till then will that check the surrounding top/ down / left right and be able to change zeros to one ??

Comment: Let's say in one iteration you change 4 0's to a 1.  Do they wait concurrently or separately.  Is the wait period 4 hours or 1 hour?

Comment: Once a machine receives a file it will wait for one hour to send it to another one ... so basically all of them will wait for one hour

Comment: But if they are all waiting for 1 hour at the same time, then that counts for 1 hour, right?

Comment: Not sure I told you the question as stated ... but the second iteration I wrote in the question happens at the end of the first hour ... and the solution for that typical test case would be 2 hours because the third iteration would have all of them into ones

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to update `grid`, use `grid.get(y).get(x)` to check the grid and `grid.get(y).set(x, value)` to update the grid. If you're not allowed to update the grid, start by copying the values into a `int[][]` 2D array, then use that instead in the solution below.

Scan the grid for `0` values, and add the coordinates to a `Queue<Point>`, e.g. an `ArrayDeque<Point>`, where `Point` is an object with two `int` fields, e.g. the [`java.awt.Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class.

We do that to ensure good performance, with run time complexity as *O(nm)*, where `n` and `m` are the width and height of the grid.

Start a loop with `i = 1`. In the loop, iterate the queue. If the point has a neighboring value equal to `i`, set the points value to `i + 1`, otherwise add the point to a second queue. At the end, replace the first queue with the second queue, increase `i` by 1 and do it again, until the queue is empty.

The result is a progression of the 2D matrix like this:

```
0 1 1 0 1   →   2 1 1 2 1   →   2 1 1 2 1   →   2 1 1 2 1
0 1 0 0 0   →   2 1 2 0 2   →   2 1 2 3 2   →   2 1 2 3 2
0 0 0 0 1   →   0 2 0 2 1   →   3 2 3 2 1   →   3 2 3 2 1
0 0 0 1 0   →   0 0 2 1 2   →   0 3 2 1 2   →   4 3 2 1 2
```

The highest value in the matrix is 4, so the answer is 3 hours, one less than highest value.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the code, which copies the input to a 2D array, and lowers the values by 1, since it makes more sense that way.

```
static int hours(int rows, int columns, List<List<Integer>> grid) {
    // Build hourGrid, where value is the number of hours until the
    // node can send, with MAX_VALUE meaning the node cannot send.
    // Also build queue of nodes that cannot send.
    int[][] hourGrid = new int[rows][columns];
    Queue<Point> pending = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            if (grid.get(y).get(x) == 0) {
                hourGrid[y][x] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                pending.add(new Point(x, y));
            }
        }
    }

    // Keep iterating the queue until all pending nodes can send.
    // Each iteration adds 1 hour to the total time.
    int hours = 0;
    for (; ! pending.isEmpty(); hours++) {
        // Check all pending nodes if they can receive data
        Queue<Point> notYet = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for (Point p : pending) {
            if ((p.x > 0           && hourGrid[p.y][p.x - 1] <= hours)
             || (p.x < columns - 1 && hourGrid[p.y][p.x + 1] <= hours)
             || (p.y > 0           && hourGrid[p.y - 1][p.x] <= hours)
             || (p.y < rows - 1    && hourGrid[p.y + 1][p.x] <= hours)) {
                // Node can receive from a neighbor, so will be able to send in 1 hour
                hourGrid[p.y][p.x] = hours + 1;
            } else {
                // Not receiving yet, so add to queue for next round
                notYet.add(p);
            }
        }
        pending = notYet;
    }
    return hours;
}
```

For testing, building a `List<List<Integer>>`, and sending in separate `rows` and `columns` values, is cumbersome, so here is a helper method:

```
static int hours(int[][] grid) {
    final int rows = grid.length;
    final int columns = grid[0].length;
    List<List<Integer>> gridList = new ArrayList<>(rows);
    for (int[] row : grid) {
        List<Integer> rowList = new ArrayList<>(columns);
        for (int value : row)
            rowList.add(value); // autoboxes
        gridList.add(rowList);
    }
    return hours(rows, columns, gridList);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(hours(new int[][] { // data from question
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
}));
System.out.println(hours(new int[][] { // data from answer
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
}));
```

*Output*

```
2
3
```

Comment: i totally appreciate this info grid.get(y).set(x, value) i was searching for it. the only issue in my solution is that you won't be able to edit the main grid till the overall iteration is over. in other words when a node with 1 changes the neighbors it will only affect them in the next iteration though they will still be the same for the current one ( at least my understanding for that)

Comment: I don't totally understand your theory for the answer so if you can share some code would be excellent but the only issue would be that the solution is 2 hours not 3

Comment: @RaymondHaniArtin My example is not the same as your example, so the solution to *my* example is 3 hours.

Comment: Oh okayy thanks a lot then I will try to write that code but wouldnt that make the complexity o(n^2) ?or o(mn) is different ??

Comment: @RaymondHaniArtin If `n` is the number of nodes, i.e. `n = width * height`, then this answer is _O(n)_ and [answer by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59450431/5221149) is _O(n²)_ (worst case, i.e. when matrix is 1*n with only one 1 at beginning or end).

Comment: Thanks for taking time and sharing the code, I guess this is the optimal solution ... I will test it and mark it as the answer thanks !

Comment: However I still need some clarification ... I ve been taught that when using nested loop will by default turn the algorithm as o(n^2) so I have some confusion . So,do you have any link that would explain the calculation of algorithm in a nice way ??

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work.

```
      List<List<Integer>> grid = 
            new ArrayList<>(List.of(
      new ArrayList<>(List.of(0, 1, 1, 0, 1)),
      new ArrayList<>(List.of( 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)),
      new ArrayList<>(List.of( 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)),
      new ArrayList<>(List.of( 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))));

      int total =0; 
      while (hours(4,4,grid) > 0) {
         total++;
      }

      System.out.println(total + " hours");

   }

   public static void display(List<List<?>> grid) {
      for (List<?> row : grid) {
         System.out.println(row);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
   public static int hours(int rows, int cols, List<List<Integer>> grid) {
      int count = 0;

      // count the remaining 0's and change
      // the new guys to 1.
      for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            if (grid.get(r).get(c) == 0) {
               count++;
            }
            if (grid.get(r).get(c) == -2) {
               grid.get(r).set(c, 1);
            }
         }
      }
      if (count == 0) {
         return 0;
      }
      for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

            if (grid.get(r).get(c) == 1 && grid.get(r).get(c) != -2) {
               if (r + 1 < rows) {
                  if (grid.get(r + 1).get(c) == 0) {
                     grid.get(r + 1).set(c, -2);
                  }
               }
               if (r - 1 >= 0) {
                  if (grid.get(r - 1).get(c) == 0) {
                     grid.get(r - 1).set(c, -2);
                  }
               }
               if (c + 1 < cols) {
                  if (grid.get(r).get(c + 1) == 0) {
                     grid.get(r).set(c + 1, -2);
                  }
               }
               if (c - 1 >= 0) {
                  if (grid.get(r).get(c - 1) == 0) {
                     grid.get(r).set(c - 1, -2);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }

      return count;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why, please? Code only answers are not really helpful. It's from the explanations that we all learn.

Comment: I dont have access to PC at the moment to test it but if the output is 2 hours then i guess it is the optimal solution

Comment: However another question was to calculate the complexity of the algorithm used ... so if you want to go for that challenge share with us 

Comment: You dont wait one hour at first ... the end of the first iteration happens at the end of the first hour... and you're not allowed to change the input parameters of the method which were int rows int columns and list<list<string>>

Comment: Yes that what I mean... optimization should be considered while writing code... and definitely dynamic the size of the list may change