# What is the most efficient way of visiting neighbor elements in a 2-D array in Go?

Tags: arrays, go

The problem I met is I have to visit all the eight neighbors of an element `[i, j]` in a 2D array.

However, considering the error of array out of bound, I have to do a lot of if else statement on `[i-1, j]` or `[i+1, j]`...It's kind of verbose to me.

So I wonder if there is any efficient way to implement this kind of problem in Go?
Like error-catching system?

Comment: Go is a verbose language. It's only 4 or 8 accesses depending if you're taking those diagonally neighboring items. Just write it out in a clean straight forward conditional structure. It's still a 20-30 line function, that's not really a big deal.

Comment: I think you're approaching the problem wrong, you should know the bounds, maybe if you share some code someone can help better.

Comment: The only efficient way of doing it is by minimizing the amount of required bounds checks. But I guess that you have already figured this out. Now how to do it entirely depends on your use case. Do you scan the whole array in a loop (cellular automaton)? Or are you checking elements at random? Sharing some code would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution would follow the [pseudo-code presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652123/6309).
See for a Go example this [yucchiy/minesweeper `field.go#GetNeighbors(x, y int)`](https://github.com/yucchiy/minesweeper/blob/c02cede38aa6b046eca399b70b9f6d3e081a11bb/field.go#L130-L150).

It depends if you can enrich your data structure with an actual Array object composed of Fields, each one knowing its neighbor. Then "visiting neighbor elements in a 2-D array" become asking a Field for the list of Fields which are its neighbor.